# Set position on block depends on store config

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to show my block at top and bottom per page, depends on my store config (field where I choose "show on top / show at the bottom")
Please advice how I can use this config and show my block only at top or at the bottom per page.

Thanks.

Comment: Also I would like to clarify, that I have two sections with reference name="head" or reference name=content after="-", for example and I need to choose this section depends on my config. How it can be done in a proper way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should get you pointed in the right direction with a little modification.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892476/how-to-get-data-from-magento-system-configuration

Comment: Yes, but how I can choose, what block use form layout.xml (reference name="head" or reference name=content after="-"), depends on my config for example. Thanks.